# Problems with rigging a modeled character in 2.92

Tags: rigging

I've modeled a cyborg/droid looking character and got my meta rig set up fine but when I generate my rig several pieces of my fingers and side plating on the forearms and two toes are separated and don't follow when I pose. the legs are modeled in the same fashion and there's no problem with either of those.

I researched a little about weight painting and when I tried doing that the areas Im describing lit up red and took I guess but still no change. I get the concept but don't know what to do from there as I'm not a Blender guru some any explaining in laymen's terms would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Screenshots or images means better help usually, but will try. The arms may have lit up red, but does that mean they were in the right vertex group? If they are all assigned to the wrong one, they will not move with the correct bone. I’ve had situations happen where I accidentally assigned one arm to the other arms bone, and it moved with it.

Comment: I think I understand what your saying but do not know about vertex grouping where could I research this topic as this is my first attempt at rigging so not really sure what Im doing. Thank You so Much for the info!

Comment: As a good fallback, you can view or download the Blender Manual from docs.blender.org for free. It even includes its own search engine.

Comment: Ok I figured out the whole weight painting step including changing things that should not be assigned to. I have my mesh parented to my meta rig at the moment so do I unparent that before generating my rig? I have tested movement on all arms and legs and everything is moving as it should so dont want to mess it up

Comment: I do not know much about generated rigs, but I am pretty sure that generating a rig from an armature will not have any affect on the mesh.

Comment: Ok....Thanks for the input very appreciated